# Chrome Extension Not Responding (browser_action & background script)

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Any idea why the following chrome extension responds very slow when checkboxes are clicked?

I tried to use page_action, but that prevented the `chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor` functionality.

I want to change the extension's icon from the background.js script, but then options.html doesn't work properly.

**manifest.json:**

```
{
    "name": "name",
    "description": "desc",
    "manifest_version" : 2,
    "version" : "0.1.0",
    "icons": {
    },
    "web_accessible_resources": [
    ],
    "options_page": "options.html",
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"],
      "persistent": false
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "def title",
        "default_popup": "options.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "background",
        "notifications",
        "http://*/",
        "https://*/"
    ]
}
```

**options.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <div class="p-2">
        <form>
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="input_text" id="input_text" />
                <label for="input_text">Text input</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" name="cb1" id="cb1" />
                <label for="cb1">Checkbox 1</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" name="cb2" id="cb2" />
                <label for="cb2">Checkbox 2</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**background.js:**

```
function changeIconBackground() {
  chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color: [255, 255, 0, 200]});
}
changeIconBackground();
```

Comment: Since there's no JavaScript in options.html, the observed slowness must be a bug in Chrome, you can report it on https://crbug.com.

Comment: @wOxxOm - I've opened a ticket: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1082159